# Filter angular router events for navigation start and end

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router

I need to filter the `NavigationEnd` event from the router events and run some code but only when navigation start event has a property `navigationTrigger === 'imperative'`.

Right now my code is like this:

```js
this.router.events.pipe (
    filter(e => e instanaceof NavigationEnd)
).subscribe(val => {});
```

How can I change this to emit `NavigationStart` event also and first check if the property navigationTrigger has value 'imperative'.

**PROBLEM** - I want to only call the subscription code when the router event is triggered by user manually and not on any redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `switchMap` operator. You should also check if the navigation is not cancelled/errorred, and if it's either cancelled or ended you end the inner `switchMap` subscription by using the `take(1)` operator. I'm not entirely sure if the `NavigationCancel`/`NavigationError` check is necessary. That depends on your use-case

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationStart && e.navigationTrigger === 'imperative'),
  switchMap(() => this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd
      || e instanceof NavigationCancel
      || e instanceof NavigationError
    ),
    take(1),
    filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ))
).subscribe(val => {});
```